# VBA:Trigger macro on column filter

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way we can trigger a macro function on column filter in excel??

Please help

Thanks.

Comment: no there isn't, but if you tell us more about what you want to do we can help

Comment: @user2144293, do you mean 'user-defined-function' or 'sub macro'?

Comment: I need to check if columns filtered has data in those or null.

Comment: That is very easy :) Use offset.Specialcells to check if it has any rows. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s

Comment: Have to trigger as soon as I filter.

Comment: There is no direct way to capture it like @Philip mentioned. You can use the Worksheet_Change Event but then there are many loop holes in that. I have an alternative to suggest. Do not let the user directly filter the data in the sheet but pop a userform from where they can filter the column. You can then from there check if the autofilter produced any results or not

Answer (score 11):

I was just thinking if I can post this answer. I guess some of you will not like it as it is not direct answer by presentation of bypass solution. However I think I can show that idea as **we don't have all project assumptions in the question.**

Let's agree- we all know that there is no event which fires after we change filtering. However, I see one option.

Changing filter could fire `Worksheet_Calculate` event (not `Worksheet_Change`). If there is any single formula within your sheet than we will fire that event each time we change filtering criteria using our mouse.

**Step 1.** put any single formula in the sheet, like in cell ZZ1 where =ZZ2

**Step 2.** I assume that our data range starts in Range(A1) and we have titles in first row (see the picture). I assume also there is nothing below that area.

[image]

**Step 3.** Put that following solution in Sheet1 module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then
    If Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No data available"
    Else
        MsgBox "There are filtering results"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

**Step 4.** Using filter would fire that event and result with following situations:

[image][image]

I hope someone will like it and can use that. Even if it's only a bypass idea.