# Excel-VBA: detect OK-event from Autofilter

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

If I press the OK-button in Excel-Autofilter (i.e. after placing a filter setting) - is there a way to detect this OK-event ???

Comment: Interesting question, but it might help if you tell us *why* you want to do that.

Comment: Try this: [Excel VBA Filter Change event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979396/excel-vba-filter-change-event-handler)

Comment: The article seems to have old links - I cannot find the "article" link explanation. Could you please give me an example on how to use Excel VBA Filter Change event handler ? thank you !

Comment: Intention: There is a column containing string-words. The autofilter can filter for equal string-words. Each string-word contains many paramter-columns to the right of the string-word-cell. The autofilter filters the string-words of course also its corresponding parameters to the right. Because each string-word has its own parameters, I would like to add "legend"-cells on top of my table. If the filter is active, the legend is shown nicely. But here is the catch: I would like to hide the legend when no autofilter is set ! (therefore the detection of the OK-event to hide/unhide the legend)

Comment: I found that one on google and there were more, such as [VBA:Trigger macro on column filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904230/vbatrigger-macro-on-column-filter) or [Running A Procedure Upon/after Autofilter](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=72860&p=374992#post374992). Hope there's something in there for you.